# Optimizing GROUP BY on JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT 
 h1.Date AS Date,
 h1.Currency AS Currency1,
 h2.Currency AS Currency2,
 h1.Account AS Account,
 SUM(h1.Size) AS Size1,
 SUM(h2.Size) AS Size2,
 h1.MaturityDate AS MaturityDate
FROM
 htable h1 JOIN htable h2 ON 
 h1.AssetClass = 'FX' AND
 h2.AssetClass = 'FX' AND
 h1.Date = h2.Date AND
 (SUBSTR(h1.Ticker, 7, 3) <> h1.Currency) AND
 (SUBSTR(h2.Ticker, 7, 3) = h2.Currency) AND
 h1.SecID = h2.SecID
GROUP BY h1.Date, h1.Currency, h2.Currency, h1.Account, h1.MaturityDate
HAVING SUM(h1.Size) <> 0 AND SUM(h2.Size) <> 0)
```

The query above WITHOUT the GROUP BY clause is quick when queried for a specific *Date*.

The problem is when I add the GROUP BY, it becomes extremely slow, even if I add a specific *Date* to the HAVING clause.

I have already added indexes for *htable* for the columns *Date*, *AssetClass*, *SecID*, *Currency*, *MaturityDate*, and also a an index for the combination of (*Date*, *Account*, *Currency*, *MaturityDate*).

This is being done in MySQL. Do you have any tips on how to speed up the query (I plan on using the query for a view definition)? Thanks!

Comment: You should add the specific date to the `where` clause, not the `having` clause.  *Before* aggregation rather than *after*.

Comment: You could probably move the ` = 'FX'` conditions to a WHERE clause, along with the `substr` conditions.

Comment: You may try to use a cursor inside a procedure, composed of your query without `the GROUP BY clause`, and derive "out" argument values by      
 `Flow Control Statements`

Comment: and/or you might convert the `h2.AssetClass = 'FX'` to `h1.AssetClass = h2.AssetClass` after moving `h1.AssetClass = 'FX' to the WHERE

Comment: What is the data type of `h1.Date`? `h1.AssetClass = 'FX'` isn't really a filter on your `JOIN`, so I'm not sure how MySQL will optimize it. You can try `ON h1.AssetClass = h2.AssetClass AND h2.AssetClass = 'FX1' .... ` and that might make a better query plan, but I'm not sure. Also, `h1.Currency <> SUBSTR(h1.Ticker,7,3)` should be in a `WHERE` and not in the `JOIN`. You might be able to nest it in a subquery to make it more performant.

Comment: In addition to SHOW CREATE statements for all relevant tables, questions about query performance always require the EXPLAIN for the given query.

Answer (score 1):

The first index that come to mind I can see can improve the performance of your query is:

```
htable (AssetClass, Date, SecID) -- if Date is more selective than SecID
```

Or

```
htable (AssetClass, SecID, Date) -- if SecId is more selective than Date
```

Now, if you want to go a step further, you can index a virtual column for `SUBSTR(h2.Ticker, 7, 3)`, by:

```
alter table htable add ticker_currency varchar(3) 
  generated always as (SUBSTR(h2.Ticker, 7, 3)) virtual;
```

Then, add the index:

```
htable (AssetClass, SecID, Date, ticker_currency)
```